# Socket server between Unity and Raspberry doesn't connect

Tags: python, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi

So I am trying to send data from the raspberry pi to unity.
I trying to create socket server to do so.

I can get the socket server running on the raspberry pi and can also look at the port with `netstat -tulpn | grep :5005` in the terminal on the machine where the python script is running.
I also tried it on my mac and it also showed up as a TCP-server.

However when I try to connect to the same port and ip via Unity or on another machine it doesn't work. I also can't seem to find the port when listing all of the ports with `netstat`.
Unity spits out a "Connection refused" error.

Here is the code in Unity in C#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class ClientSocket : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool socketReady = false;
    TcpClient mySocket;
    public NetworkStream theStream;
    StreamWriter theWriter;
    StreamReader theReader;
    public String Host = "192.168.8.137";
    public Int32 Port = 5005;

    void Start()
    {
        setupSocket();
        TextMessage("SocketTest");
    }


    public void setupSocket()
    {                            // Socket setup here
        try
        {
            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            socketReady = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket error:" + e);                // catch any exceptions
        }
    }
    public void TextMessage(string message)
    {
        if (socketReady == true)
        {
            theWriter.Write(message);
            theWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code in python, which should be running on the raspberry pi.

```
import socket
import sys

backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.8.137', 5005))
s.listen(1)

try:
    print ("is waiting")
    client, address = s.accept()

    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print (data)

finally:
    print("closing socket")
    cient.close()
    s.close()
```

I'm new to socket servers, but I really trying to accomplish a connection here.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue

Comment: Also what do you mean by `should be running on the raspberry pi` ? .. is it running or not? ^^ And does the PI actually have that IP?

Comment: Have you tried to use `nmap` against the PI to see which ports are available for remote devices? `nmap -A 192.168.8.137` should be enough

Comment: Firewalls are all disabled.
NMap shows up the port no matter on which device it is run. So it shows up on my MacBook and on the raspberry pi. Yet Unity still can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

am pretty sure you need to encode the data that you about to send in c# TcpClient
adding an example from my final project:

```
string data = "Hello Server!"; //the message in string (important it will be string)
byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data); //encoded the message using unicode (utf-16)
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); //get the tcp client stream
stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length); //write the message to the stream
```

and in the server you suppose to have something like that:

```
msg = clnt.recv(1024) #reciving the data
msg = msg.decode("utf-16") #decoding the data
print(msg) #printing the data
```

and i think thats it
and i would recommend using port above 10000 because most of the ports can be used